# blackberry and android apps

Tags: android, blackberry, operating-system, blackberry-10

I'm really curious to know how blackberry the company let's the blackberry OS install the apk package and the app runs like it was built to run on a blackberry. I've been looking for information on how they do it but can't find anything relevant.

Maybe there is some kind of compatibility layer built in the OS to let android apps run?

I thought I'd ask I think it's pretty neat how that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compatability layer is built into the OS. QNX and Android on ARM use the same system call syemantics. BB10 system calls are able to distinquish the origin of the call (QNX or Android) and provide the appropriate service. This was introduced in 10.2.

Comment: But there's no Java VM  involved, isn't it? It must be compiled to native I guess. Otherwise it would be funny that RIM ditched the JavaME platform to avoid paying Oracle and then they licensed big G's Dalvik VM.

Comment: The JVM is part of the Android OS so it is able to run in the BB Android run time.